# Encoding YUV file (uncompressed video) to mp4 playable file using H264 encoding with ffmpeg c++ (NOT command line)

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

My goal is to encode a yuv file to a playable mp4 file (can be played with VLC) with ffmpeg c++ code.

First I have a source_1920x1080p30.mpg video (compressed) file.
Using ffmpeg CLI I created output_test.yuv file.
`ffmpeg -i source_1920x1080p30.mpg -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p output_test.yuv`

I used `ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 1920x1080 output_test.yuv` which played well.
Also used `ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -s:v 1920x1080 -r 30 -i output_test.yuv -c:v libx264 vid.mp4`
and the new vid.mp4 was playble.
So I have good yuv file.

I want to encode this output_test.yuv YUV file with ffmpeg by code.
I tested the ffmpeg site encode example [ffmpeg site encode example](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/encode_video_8c-example.html) and it was running good.

In that example, the frames are self made inside the code - But I want that the input would be my YUV file.

Becasue I used ffmpeg CLI to convert YUV to mp4 (as noted above) I am sure it can be done by code - but I dont how..

So, I tried to add to their example the use of the methods:
avformat_open_input() & avformat_find_stream_info()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern "C" {
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
 
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
} 
// ffmpeg method.
static void encode(AVCodecContext *enc_ctx, AVFrame *frame, AVPacket *pkt,
                   FILE *outfile)
{
    int ret;
 
    /* send the frame to the encoder */
    if (frame)
        printf("Send frame %3" PRId64 "\n", frame->pts);
 
    ret = avcodec_send_frame(enc_ctx, frame);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending a frame for encoding\n");
        exit(1);
    }
 
    while (ret >= 0) {
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(enc_ctx, pkt);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
            return;
        else if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error during encoding\n");
            exit(1);
        }
 
        printf("Write packet %3" PRId64 " (size=%5d)\n", pkt->pts, pkt->size);
        fwrite(pkt->data, 1, pkt->size, outfile);
        av_packet_unref(pkt);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    
    int ret;
    char errbuf[100];

    AVFormatContext* ifmt_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();

    AVDictionary* options = NULL;
    //av_dict_set(&options, "framerate", "30", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "video_size", "1920x1080", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options,"pixel_format", "yuv420p",0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "vcodec", "rawvideo", 0);

    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, "output_test.yuv", NULL, &options)) < 0) {
        av_strerror(ret, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open err=%s\n", errbuf);
    }

    const AVCodec *pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO); //Get pointer to rawvideo codec.

    AVCodecContext *pCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec); //Allocate codec context.

    //Fill the codec context based on the values from the codec parameters.
    AVStream *vid_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[0];
    avcodec_parameters_to_context(pCodecContext, vid_stream->codecpar);

    avcodec_open2(pCodecContext, pCodec, NULL); //Open the codec

    //Allocate memory for packet and frame
    AVPacket *pPacket = av_packet_alloc();
    AVFrame *pFrame = av_frame_alloc();

    // For output use:
    
    const char *filename, *codec_name;
    const AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
    int i, x, y;
    FILE *f;
    // origin ffmpeg code - AVFrame *frame;
    AVPacket *pkt;
    uint8_t endcode[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0xb7 };
 
    if (argc <= 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <output file> <codec name>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    filename = argv[1];
    codec_name = argv[2];
 
    /* find the mpeg1video encoder */
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name(codec_name);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec '%s' not found\n", codec_name);
        exit(1);
    }
 
    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!c) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
        exit(1);
    }
 
    pkt = av_packet_alloc();
    if (!pkt)
        exit(1);
 
    /* put sample parameters */
    c->bit_rate = 400000;
    /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
    c->width = 352;
    c->height = 288;
    /* frames per second */
    c->time_base = (AVRational){1, 25};
    c->framerate = (AVRational){25, 1};
 
    /* emit one intra frame every ten frames
     * check frame pict_type before passing frame
     * to encoder, if frame->pict_type is AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I
     * then gop_size is ignored and the output of encoder
     * will always be I frame irrespective to gop_size
     */
    c->gop_size = 10;
    c->max_b_frames = 1;
    c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
 
    if (codec->id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
        av_opt_set(c->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);
 
    /* open it */
    ret = avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        //fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        exit(1);
    }
 
    f = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
// This is ffmpeg code that I removed   
//    frame = av_frame_alloc();
//    if (!frame) {
//        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
//        exit(1);
//    }
//    frame->format = c->pix_fmt;
//    frame->width  = c->width;
//    frame->height = c->height;
// 
//    ret = av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0);
//    if (ret < 0) {
//        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate the video frame data\n");
//        exit(1);
//    }

    pFrame->format = c->pix_fmt;
    pFrame->width  = c->width;
    pFrame->height = c->height;
    

    //Read video frames and pass through the decoder.
    //Note: Since the video is rawvideo, we don't really have to pass it through the decoder.
    while (av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, pPacket) >= 0) 
    {
        //The video is not encoded - passing through the decoder is simply copy the data.
        avcodec_send_packet(pCodecContext, pPacket);    //Supply raw packet data as input to the "decoder".
        avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecContext, pFrame);   //Return decoded output data from the "decoder".

        fflush(stdout);
// This is ffmpeg code that I removed  
//        /* Make sure the frame data is writable.
//           On the first round, the frame is fresh from av_frame_get_buffer()
//           and therefore we know it is writable.
//           But on the next rounds, encode() will have called
//           avcodec_send_frame(), and the codec may have kept a reference to
//           the frame in its internal structures, that makes the frame
//           unwritable.
//           av_frame_make_writable() checks that and allocates a new buffer
//           for the frame only if necessary.
//         */
//        ret = av_frame_make_writable(frame);
//        if (ret < 0)
//            exit(1);
// 
//        /* Prepare a dummy image.
//           In real code, this is where you would have your own logic for
//           filling the frame. FFmpeg does not care what you put in the
//           frame.
//         */
//        /* Y */
//        for (y = 0; y < c->height; y++) {
//            for (x = 0; x < c->width; x++) {
//                frame->data[0][y * frame->linesize[0] + x] = x + y + i * 3;
//            }
//        }
// 
//        /* Cb and Cr */
//        for (y = 0; y < c->height/2; y++) {
//            for (x = 0; x < c->width/2; x++) {
//                frame->data[1][y * frame->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
//                frame->data[2][y * frame->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + x + i * 5;
//            }
//        }
 
        pFrame->pts = i;
 
        /* encode the image */
        encode(c, pFrame, pkt, f);
    }
 
    /* flush the encoder */
    encode(c, NULL, pkt, f);
 
    /* Add sequence end code to have a real MPEG file.
       It makes only sense because this tiny examples writes packets
       directly. This is called "elementary stream" and only works for some
       codecs. To create a valid file, you usually need to write packets
       into a proper file format or protocol; see mux.c.
     */
    if (codec->id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO || codec->id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO)
        fwrite(endcode, 1, sizeof(endcode), f);
    fclose(f);
 
    avcodec_free_context(&c);
    av_frame_free(&pFrame);
    av_packet_free(&pkt);
 
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT** : I added combined code of ffmpeg and reading/decoding from YUV file according @Rotem (thanks). Frame from decoder pushed right to encode() method of ffmpeg. The out video was not good... Should I manipulate the YUV input frame before send it to encode() method? if yes how to do it?

Comment: The source code for [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#get-sources) is available.  You can download it and look at it yourself, and step through it line-by-line with a debugger.

Comment: @Eljay Thanks. I have problems trying to use the debuuger. I am with Linux ubuntu 22.04.2 and Netbeans as IDE. I downloaded the code and compile it according ffmpeg site (./configure etc...,  code sources are at /home/.../ffmpeg_sources etc.) I got the error in netbeans : cd '/home/vboxuser/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg'
/bin/sh ./configure CC=/usr/bin/gcc CXX=/usr/bin/g++ CFLAGS="-g3 -gdwarf-2" CXXFLAGS="-g3 -gdwarf-2"
Unknown option "CC=/usr/bin/gcc".
See ./configure --help for available options.

RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 480ms)  - But it should be for another question I guess.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to use `avformat_open_input` with raw video input.  Why not simply using `fread` for reading the raw video frames?

Answer (score 0):

Since the input file contains raw video, we don't really have to use `avformat_open_input` - we may simply read the input video frames using `fread`.
(Allocate AVFrame size 1920x1080 YUV420p pixel format, read Y, read U, read V...).

If we really want to use `avformat_open_input` with raw input video, we must set the size and pixel format by setting the `AVDictionary **options` argument.

The `options` are the equivalent to setting `-pixel_format yuv420p` and `-video_size 1920x1080` in the FFplay command:

`ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 1920x1080`

---

Example for setting `options` and calling `avformat_open_input`:

```
AVDictionary* options = NULL;
av_dict_set(&options, "video_size", "1920x1080", 0); //Equivalent to -video_size 1920x1080 
av_dict_set(&options,"pixel_format", "yuv420p",0); //Equivalent to -pixel_format yuv420p
av_dict_set(&options, "vcodec", "rawvideo", 0); //Equivalent to -vcodec rawvideo

avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, "input.yuv", NULL, &options)
```

---

Example for reading the video frames and passing through the decoding sequence:

```
extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}

#include <stdio.h>

//Build raw input video file:
//ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=1920x1080:rate=1:duration=10 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo input.yuv

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int ret;
    char errbuf[100];

    AVFormatContext* ifmt_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();

    AVDictionary* options = NULL;
    //av_dict_set(&options, "framerate", "30", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "video_size", "1920x1080", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options,"pixel_format", "yuv420p",0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "vcodec", "rawvideo", 0);

    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, "input.yuv", NULL, &options)) < 0) {
        av_strerror(ret, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open err=%s\n", errbuf);
    }

    //Raw video doesn't contain any stream information.
    //if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx, 0)) < 0) {
    //    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to retrieve input stream information");
    //}
    
    const AVCodec *pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO); //Get pointer to rawvideo codec.

    AVCodecContext *pCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec); //Allocate codec context.

    //Fill the codec context based on the values from the codec parameters.
    AVStream *vid_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[0];
    avcodec_parameters_to_context(pCodecContext, vid_stream->codecpar);

    avcodec_open2(pCodecContext, pCodec, NULL); //Open the codec

    //Allocate memory for packet and frame
    AVPacket *pPacket = av_packet_alloc();
    AVFrame *pFrame = av_frame_alloc();

    //Read video frames and pass through the decoder.
    //Note: Since the video is rawvideo, we don't really have to pass it through the decoder.
    while (av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, pPacket) >= 0) 
    {
        //The video is not encoded - passing through the decoder is simply copy the data.
        avcodec_send_packet(pCodecContext, pPacket);    //Supply raw packet data as input to the "decoder".
        avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecContext, pFrame);   //Return decoded output data from the "decoder".
    }
    
    avcodec_free_context(&pCodecContext);
    avformat_free_context(ifmt_ctx);
    av_frame_free(&pFrame);
    av_packet_free(&pPacket);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Notes:

- For simplicity, the above code sample doesn't check for errors.
- Passing the raw video through the "decoder" is a simple data copy.
  Reading the data from the file directly to `AVFrame`, is probably more efficient (saves memory copies).
- In case we are reading the data using `fread`, may we have to read it row by row (it is not guarantied that the data is going to be continues in memory).
  Using the current version of FFmpeg, frame width of `1920` is continues in memory (Y plane is continues, U plane is continues and V plane is continues).

---

### Update:

**Saving the content of `pFrame` after `avcodec_receive_frame` to binary file for testing**:

For verifying that the content of `pFrame` are the same as the raw input frames, we may save Y, U and V planes of each `pFrame` to binary file (name it `"output_frames.yuv"`).
The content of "output_frames.yuv" should be identical to the `"input.yuv"` (identical since we are working with raw video).

Code sample:

```
extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}

#include <stdio.h>

//Build raw input video file:
//ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=1920x1080:rate=1:duration=10 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo input.yuv

//Play output_frames.yuv using FFplay:
//ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 1 output_frames.yuv

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int ret;
    char errbuf[100];

    AVFormatContext* ifmt_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();

    AVDictionary* options = NULL;
    //av_dict_set(&options, "framerate", "30", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "video_size", "1920x1080", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options,"pixel_format", "yuv420p",0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "vcodec", "rawvideo", 0);

    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, "input.yuv", NULL, &options)) < 0) {
        av_strerror(ret, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open err=%s\n", errbuf);
        return ret;
    }

    FILE *f = fopen("output_frames.yuv", "wb"); //Open file for storing the content of avcodec_receive_frame (for testing)
   
    const AVCodec *pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO); //Get pointer to rawvideo codec.

    AVCodecContext *pCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec); //Allocate codec context.

    //Fill the codec context based on the values from the codec parameters.
    AVStream *vid_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[0];
    avcodec_parameters_to_context(pCodecContext, vid_stream->codecpar);

    avcodec_open2(pCodecContext, pCodec, NULL); //Open the codec

    //Allocate memory for packet and frame
    AVPacket *pPacket = av_packet_alloc();
    AVFrame *pFrame = av_frame_alloc();

    //Read video frames and pass through the decoder.
    //Note: Since the video is rawvideo, we don't really have to pass it through the decoder.
    while (av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, pPacket) >= 0) 
    {
        //The video is not encoded - passing through the decoder is simply copy the data.
        avcodec_send_packet(pCodecContext, pPacket);    //Supply raw packet data as input to the "decoder".
        avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecContext, pFrame);   //Return decoded output data from the "decoder".

        //Save Y, U and V (YUV420p format) to binary output file for testing.
        fwrite(pFrame->data[0], 1, 1920*1080, f);     //Save Y channel (assume plane is continuous in memory).
        fwrite(pFrame->data[1], 1, 1920*1080/4, f);   //Save U channel (assume plane is continuous in memory).
        fwrite(pFrame->data[2], 1, 1920*1080/4, f);   //Save V channel (assume plane is continuous in memory).
    }
    
    avcodec_free_context(&pCodecContext);
    avformat_free_context(ifmt_ctx);
    av_frame_free(&pFrame);
    av_packet_free(&pPacket);
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

After executing the above code sample, the content of `"output_frames.yuv"` and `"input.yuv"` is identical.

Comment: Thanks! YUV input read is one stage of what I need. Do it step by step, to overcome problems 'one a t a time'. **What I actually need is 1. reading uncompressed frames from a private memory object, that send me uncompressed frames live from camera, 2. ffmpeg need in some way to get them, and 3. encode them**. I Combined your code sample and ffmpeg encode sample. The video was not as I expected at all. I took the YUV frame from decoder and pass it to encode() method instead of their dummy frame. I EDIT my quest with updated code. Can you specify what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: First, it's impolite to radically change the question after being answered. Second, the YUV frame from the decoder are **not dummy frame** - I updated my answer with an example that tests your claims, and the frames are correct. Third, questions in Stack Overflow site should be focused in specific problems - you don't suppose to ask something like "reading uncompressed frames from a private memory object, that send me uncompressed frames live from camera, 2. ffmpeg need in some way to get them, and 3. encode them"... (ask about specific issue of your implementation, as in your original post).

Comment: thanks again, got the messge. Although, subject of this question was encoding YUV to mp4, anyway, according your advice, I will try to do what I need and make a new question on each problem I will encounter.